# How to assign asp:RequiredFieldValidator to asp:TextBox with jquery/javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

Just wondering, will it be possible to assign the request validation to asp:TextBox with jquery/javascript?

I have the following code will create a checkbox with a textbox next to it:

```
    <tr>   
        <th class="graytext r">Add Reps to Team:</th>
        <td>           
         <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"
                DataSourceID="dsEmployees" EnableViewState="false"
                GridLines="None" CssClass="clGridDirectory">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="employee_name" CssClass="employee_name" Text='<%# Eval("fullname") %>'/> 
                      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="employeeidToRep" Value='<%# Eval("employeeid") %>'/>
                      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="repID" Text='<%# Eval("rep_id") %>'  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>       
           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsEmployees" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="app_staff_without_team_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
          </asp:SqlDataSource>        
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Just wondering, will it be possible for me to assign the asp:RequiredFieldValidator to the textbox when checkbox is checked or removed the asp:RequiredFieldValidator when checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET renders a client-side function named `ValidatorEnable` that you can use to enable/disable a validator on the fly. Just called it from the CheckBox's click event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkBoxID').click(function() {
        var validator = document.getElementById('validatorId');
        ValidatorEnable(validator, $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the CssClass attribute on the TextBox, such as `CssClass="RepClass"` and try to disable the required field validator in the 'click' event:

so...something like this...

```
$(".RepClass").click(function() 
{
    $(".RepClass").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

not 100% this will work, but worth a try!

Comment: -1: I don't like to down-vote, but there's a few problems with this solution: 1) If you apply the class to the TextBox, then `$(".RepClass").click` will attach an event handler to the TextBox, not the CheckBox; 2) If the function did work, it would operate on all of the controls at once, not just one at a time; 3) Finally, the function would only disable. It wouldn't reenable, which is a requirement.

Comment: That's why I said not 100% sure this will work... I don't have time to actually test all of this... it was just a suggestion. You shouldn't vote down in a situation where the user says 'not 100% sure'.

Comment: Like I said, I hate to down-vote, and I wouldn't have if you had been almost right, but this answer has a lot of problems. If you are not a 100% sure of an answer, a better place for your input would be in the comments section.